# method returning template class C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, pointers

I want to make a template vector, but there's a problem when I return the iterator.
I've been searching all the internet and haven't found any solution.
Here's the code:

```
template <class Element>
class VectorDinamic {
public:
VectorDinamic();
void add(Element el);
Element get(int poz);
~VectorDinamic();
void update(Element el,int poz);
int len();

//template <class Element>
//I get errors here: missing type specifier, unexpected token precedin ";" , missing  ";" before "<"
vectorDinamicIterator<Element>* iterator();
void del(Element el);

private:
Element* elems;
int lg;
int capacitate;
void resize();
};

template <class Element>
class vectorDinamicIterator{
public:
vectorDinamicIterator(VectorDinamic* vect){
    this->curent=0;
    this->vec = vect;
}
Element element()
{
    return vec->get(this->curent);
}
void next(){
    curent++;
}
private:
int curent;
VectorDinamic* vec;

};

template <class Element>
VectorDinamic<Element>::VectorDinamic() {
capacitate = INIT_CAPACITY;
elems = new Element[capacitate];
lg = 0;
}
//I get errors down here: iterator is not a member of VectorDinamic<Element>, 
template <class Element>
vectorDinamicIterator<Element>* VectorDinamic<Element>::iterator()
{
vectorDinamicIterator iter = new vectorDinamicIterator(this);
return iter;
}
```

I left out some method implementations to keep the code short, I added comment where I get the errors and I don't know why. Whithout the "iterator" method, the code works very well.

Comment: What errors? Why all this code? Show us your [testcase](http://sscce.org). **You probably need `typename`.**

Comment: Is there a line `template <class Element>` missing before `class VectorDinamic {`? Otherwise, how's `Element` defined?

Comment: yep sorry ... wait a sec, I'll edit

Comment: Do you really need to return a *dynamically allocated* (i.e. using `new`) `vectorDinamicIterator`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a (forward) declaration of `vectorDinamicIterator`. Every name has to be declared before it is used.

```
template < class Element >
class vectorDinamicIterator;

template <class Element>
class VectorDinamic {
public:
    VectorDinamic();
    void add(Element el);
    Element get(int poz);
    ~VectorDinamic();
    void update(Element el,int poz);
    int len();

    vectorDinamicIterator<Element>* iterator(); // <- name must be known
    void del(Element el);

private:
    Element* elems;
    int lg;
    int capacitate;
    void resize();
};

template <class Element>
class vectorDinamicIterator{
public:
    typedef VectorDynamic<Element> Vector;  //<---- specify template argument!

    vectorDinamicIterator(Vector* vect){
        this->curent=0;
        this->vec = vect;
    }
    Element element()
    {
        return vec->get(this->curent);
    }
    void next(){
        curent++;
    }
private:
    int curent;
    Vector* vec;
};
```

Yam Marcovic is right that you also need to specify the template argument in the definition of `VectorDinamic<Element>::iterator()`:

```
template <class Element>
VectorDinamic<Element>::VectorDinamic() {
    capacitate = INIT_CAPACITY;
    elems = new Element[capacitate];
    lg = 0;
}

template <class Element>
vectorDinamicIterator<Element>* VectorDinamic<Element>::iterator()
{
    vectorDinamicIterator<Element>* iter =
        new vectorDinamicIterator<Element>(this);
    return iter;
    // or simply
    // return new vectorDinamicIterator<Element>(this);
    // but I don't see why you return a pointer to a dynamically allocated
    // iterator, instead of just an iterator
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You lack specifying the template in the variable declaration and its constructor.

To fix, simply `return new vectorDinamicIterator<Element>(this);`

EDIT: Oh yeah, and as DyP noticed, you're lacking a forward declaration. For some reasons I didn't set my eyes on that part.

Comment: By the way, in your code, you didn't do as I say. Now you're assigning your pointer to a stack variable. You need to declare it as a pointer if you don't want to simply return it immediately.